# Trying to access object property from another object always returns the property's initial value

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have created two classes of objects in PaperScript: `Node`s and `Line`s. Each Line has a `this.nodes` property which is an array that references two Node objects, one for each end of the line. Nodes have a `this.dragging` property which is initialized as `false` when the Node object is created, but gets set to `true` on a `onMouseDown` event and gets set back to `false` at `onMouseUp`. This is so that I can keep track whether or not the Node is meant to be moving at a point in time.

Now I want to be able to check from the `Line` objects if its associated Nodes are being dragged at any point in time. For this I have an if statement that checks whether `(this.nodes[0].dragging == true || this.nodes[1].dragging == true)`. If that returns true then further action can happen.

The problem is that both `this.nodes[i].dragging`s always returns false, regardless of whether I am dragging the Node or not. Why does this happen? Especially when I check the value of `this.dragging` from within the `Node` object it does return the correct value of true when dragging and false otherwise.

EDIT included some code:

The following is a condensed version of my code. The important bit is the `this.dragging` variable.

```
function Node(pos) {

 ///// Stuff

  this.dragging = false;
  this.node.onMouseDown = function(event) {
    this.dragging = true;
    // Do other stuff
  }
  this.node.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
    if (this.dragging == true) {
       // Do stuff
    }
  }
  this.node.onMouseUp = function(event) {
    // Do stuff
    this.dragging = false;
  }
}
```

The following is (part of) the constructor for the Line object:

```
function Line(p1, p2) {
  this.nodes = [p1, p2];

  ///// Stuff

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.nodes[0].dragging === true || this.nodes[1].dragging === true) {
      // True
    } else {
      // False
    }
  }
}
```

2nd EDIT commenter requested how I instantiate these objects:

I instantiate them as follows:

```
var nodeNum = 7;
var lineConnections = [{
    from: 0,to: 1}
    ,{from: 0,to: 2}
    ,{from: 0,to: 3}
    ,{from: 0,to: 4}
    ,{from: 1,to: 2}
    ,{from: 1,to: 5}
    ,{from: 2,to: 3}
    ,{from: 2,to: 4}
    ,{from: 3,to: 5}
    ,{from: 4,to: 5}
    ,{from: 2,to: 5}
]

function init() {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodeNum; i++) {
    Nodes[i] = new Node();
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < lineConnections.length; i++) {
    Lines[i] = new Line(Nodes[lineConnections[i].from], Nodes[lineConnections[i].to]);
  }
}

init();
```

A live demo is available at http://aronadler.com/experiment/

Comment: Well first off, decent explination, but we cannot begin to guess without some code. Kindly post your classes constructors and such. JFiddle would be nice for working with if its more complex.

Comment: initial thoughts, I would probably use the === operator for testing as == true can sometimes behave wrong depending on how the property is interpreted.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get the contents of my PaperScript file to work in JSFiddle so is it enough if I link you to my domain where this is hosted? The project is currently live at http://aronadler.com/experiment/

Comment: And by the way, using === doesn't work either :(

Comment: Just added some code (and cleaned it up in the edits). I hope this helps you make sense of it!

Comment: Your two functions definition seem to be ok. Whether possible add the code snippet which you are instantiating these objects, so we can have a big picture of it.

Comment: Just added my initialiser function. Note though that everything renders properly so the problem doesn't lie there, it's just that the Line objects can't access the `Node[i].dragging` property's actual value, they constantly just show it as its initial value, namely false, even when it isn't.

Comment: You should post the code where you're attaching `onMouseDown` to the DOM; See my guess for what's going on below.

Comment: But I think this is for sure a "this is not the `this` you're looking for" issue.

Comment: But it does return the initial value assigned to `this.dragging`, so it's not like it's returning `undefined`. Also when I initialize 'dragging' with a value of `true` it then does return true when I call it. It just doesn't update with the live value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `this`, as in `this.dragging` in the following code refers to the global object (window), not the object you created.

`this.node.onMouseDown = function(event) {
    this.dragging = true;
    // Do other stuff
  }
  this.node.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
    if (this.dragging == true) {
       // Do stuff
    }
  }
  this.node.onMouseUp = function(event) {
    // Do stuff
    this.dragging = false;
  }`

You can check by seeing if the global variable dragging has been created. I can't really modify your code unless it's in fiddle or some other location where it's easy to work with, but you should be able to fix it either by binding each of the mouse handling functions to this as in:

  `this.node.onMouseUp = function(event) {
    // Do stuff
    this.dragging = false;
  }.bind(this)`

or by creating a closure with a local reference to this that won't change, as in:

`self = this;`

then refer to `self` from within the functions as opposed to `this`.

Comment: Actually this, in the context of a paper Tool event, refers to the Tool object, not the window.